# how to solve error: attempt to deference a null object in test class?

Tags: apex, code-coverage

Apex Class Method:

```
public static void CreateApplicationCompliance(List<PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c> applicationList){
    List<Application_Compliance__c> ApplicationComplianceList = new List<Application_Compliance__c>();
    Map<String,String> JobRefMap = new Map<String,String>();
    List<String> DocumentTypeAvailable = new List<String>();
    
    for(PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c appRec : applicationList){
        List<PeopleCloud1__Web_Document__c> ResumeFilesList = new List<PeopleCloud1__Web_Document__c>();
        ResumeFilesList = [Select Id,Name,CreatedDate,Document_Request_Date__c,PeopleCloud1__Link_to_File_Sec__c,PeopleCloud1__Expiry_Date__c,
                           PeopleCloud1__Document_Type__c from PeopleCloud1__Web_Document__c 
                           where PeopleCloud1__Document_Related_To__c =:appRec.PeopleCloud1__Candidate__c  
                           Order by CreatedDate desc];
        
        for(PeopleCloud1__Web_Document__c FileRec : ResumeFilesList){
            if(DocumentTypeAvailable.contains(FileRec.PeopleCloud1__Document_Type__c)){
                
            }
            else{
                JobRefMap.put(FileRec.PeopleCloud1__Document_Type__c,FileRec.Id);
                DocumentTypeAvailable.add(FileRec.PeopleCloud1__Document_Type__c);
            }
        }
        
        String CandidateComplianceDocuments = appRec.PeopleCloud1__Placement__r.Candidate_Compliance_Documents__c;
        List<String> lstComplianceString = CandidateComplianceDocuments.split(';');
        System.debug('-----lstComplianceString----'+lstComplianceString);
        
        for(String compliance : lstComplianceString){
            Application_Compliance__c ApplicationComplianceRec = new Application_Compliance__c();
            if(!IsApplicationCompExist(compliance,appRec.Id)){
                ApplicationComplianceRec.Job_Req__c = compliance;
                ApplicationComplianceRec.Application__c = appRec.Id;
                ApplicationComplianceRec.Candidate__c = appRec.PeopleCloud1__Candidate__c;
                ApplicationComplianceRec.Vacancy__c = appRec.PeopleCloud1__Placement__c;
                System.debug(JobRefMap.containsKey(compliance));
                if(JobRefMap.containsKey(compliance)){
                    ApplicationComplianceRec.Resume_and_Files__c = JobRefMap.get(compliance);
                    System.debug(JobRefMap.get(compliance));
                }
                ApplicationComplianceList.add(ApplicationComplianceRec);
            }
        }
    }
    upsert ApplicationComplianceList;
}
```

Test method

```
@isTest static void CreateApplicationComplianceTest(){
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name='test1';
    insert acc;
    Contact con = new Contact();
    con.LastName='srfg';
    insert con;
    
    PeopleCloud1__Placement__c vac = new PeopleCloud1__Placement__c();
    vac.Name = 'fdee';
    vac.PeopleCloud1__Company__c = acc.id;
    vac.PeopleCloud1__Online_Job_Title__c ='dfd';
    vac.PeopleCloud1__Category__c = 'Engineering';
    vac.Candidate_Compliance_Documents__c = 'Resume;CoverLetter';
    insert vac;
    system.debug(vac);
    List<PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c>b = new List<PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c>();
    PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c applicationUpdate = new PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c();
    applicationUpdate.PeopleCloud1__Placement__c = vac.id;
    applicationUpdate.PeopleCloud1__Candidate__c = con.id;
    insert applicationUpdate;
    b.add(applicationUpdate);
    List<PeopleCloud1__Web_Document__c> ResumeFilesList = new List<PeopleCloud1__Web_Document__c>();
    List<Application_Compliance__c> l = new List<Application_Compliance__c>(); 
    Application_Compliance__c n = new Application_Compliance__c(Job_Req__c='ggd');
    l.add(n);
  
    
    Test.startTest();
    ApplicationComplianceHelper.CreateApplicationCompliance(b);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

I am a beginner. I am getting the error Attempt to de-reference a null object while trying to execute this test method. How can this be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have queried parent fields before trying to access them, setting just the parent id in the lookup field is not enough.
In the test method you added `applicationUpdate` to the list `b` (please give meaningful names to your variables), but the only two fields setted are the two lookup. If you need formula fields you could either call [`recalculateFormulas()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_recalculateFormulas) if they aren't cross-object formulas, or query them (needed for cross-object formulas). If you need a parent field, you could either query them or set the reference to the object (i.e. `applicationUpdate.PeopleCloud1__Placement__r = vac`).
Once you retrieve a record via SOQL, if you try to access to a field not specified in the query, you'll get the exception: "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field".
That's why you should have retrieved every field used in the `CreateApplicationCompliance` method via SOQL right after the insert:

```java
insert applicationUpdate;
applicationUpdate = [SELECT PeopleCloud1__Placement__c, PeopleCloud1__Candidate__c, PeopleCloud1__Placement__r.Candidate_Compliance_Documents__c FROM PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c WHERE Id = :applicationUpdate.Id];
b.add(applicationUpdate);
```

You don't need to query the `Id` since a SOQL always returns it. There is only one case you need to query it: if it's the only field in the SOQL, i.e. `[SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]`.

Now the following two lines will be ok:

```java
String CandidateComplianceDocuments = appRec.PeopleCloud1__Placement__r.Candidate_Compliance_Documents__c;
List<String> lstComplianceString = CandidateComplianceDocuments.split(';');
```

`CandidateComplianceDocuments` will hold the value setted in the test method ('Resume;CoverLetter') instead of `null`, therefore `split()` can be called without throwing a NullPointerException.

By the way, in order to visualize that relationship field (`__r`) holds objects instead of primitive, you could run the following lines from Developer Console > Anonymous Window:

```java
PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c applicationUpdate  = [SELECT Name, PeopleCloud1__Placement__r.Candidate_Compliance_Documents__c FROM PeopleCloud1__Placement_Candidate__c LIMIT 1];
System.debug(JSON.serialize(applicationUpdate));
```

You'll see that:

1. It has been retrieved `PeopleCloud1__Placement__c` too
2. `PeopleCloud1__Placement__r` is a reference to a different object. Indeed it should be something like

```js
"PeopleCloud1__Placement__r": {
    "attributes": {
        "type": "PeopleCloud1__Placement__c",
        "url": "/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/PeopleCloud1__Placement__c/XXX"
    },
    "Id": "XXX",
    "Candidate_Compliance_Documents__c": "Resume;CoverLetter"
}
```

Comment: Hello RubenDG. Thank you for your help. It worked now. Can you please tell me why I had to retrieve every field used in the CreateApplicationCompliance method via SOQL right after the insert? I don't get it.

Comment: You're welcome @goel123. I updated the answer adding some details about relationship and formula fields